# executing java file using php script on web server

Tags: java, php

when I execute a java file using php command

```
exec('java test2');
```

it runs perfectly, while when I do the same thing on the web-server, it does nothing
I am unable to find the reason, can anybody please tell me the possible reason,
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure Java is installed on your web server and that you're permitted to use it?

Answer (score 1):

- Do you have Java installed in your
  web server?
- Is it added to your PATH?
- Does your webserver user have
  execution permissions on it?
- Do you have enough memory available
  as to start a JVM?

There are so many reasons why this could fail. Try logging into your server via ssh and execute 'java -version'.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you specify

```
-Djava.awt.hedless=true
```

in your java command